# Error connecting to the database for free hosting

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-hosting

I have a problem with free hosting, some time ago I wanted to connect to an online database but I get the error message:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. 

$ I_DB ["host"] = "mysqlX.000webhost.com"; 
$ I_DB ["user"] = "axx1xxx2_1xxme"; 
$ I_DB ["pass"] = "x857x49"; 
$ I_DB ["name"] = "a9x32_xdex"; 

$ Dbhost = $ i_DB ["host"]; 
$ Dbuser = $ i_DB ["user"]; 
$ Dbpass = $ i_DB ["pass"]; 
$ Dbname = $ i_DB ["name"]; 

mysql_connect ($ dbhost, $ dbuser, $ dbpass) or die (mysql_error ("Sorry error occurred on the connection to the database, while longer <meta Repeat http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>")); 
mysql_select_db ($ dbname) or die (mysql_error ("Sorry error occurred on the connection to the database, while longer <meta Repeat http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>"));
```

I am very grateful if helped.
Thanks.

Comment: Does the server permit remote connections?

Comment: You probably cannot connect to a remote DB. If the DB is local, change  `["host"] = "..."` to `["host"] = "localhost"`

Answer (score 0):

You must use localhost instead of "mysqlX.000webhost.com"

```
$ I_DB ["host"] = "mysqlX.000webhost.com";
```

Comment: Doesn't that rather depend whether the MySQL server to which one is trying to connect is on the local host?

Answer (score 0):

there can be certain reasons like offline status of your database service provider or localhost where you are not being able to set up from remote location. So try to contact with provider also.